# How to create twig macro which has output is object or array not string

Tags: twig

how to make twig macro so that output is objcet or array but not string? I need reformating diferent input to same output for javascript.

```
    {% set obj = macros.createObject( input ) %}
    <h2>{{ obj.test }}</h2>

    {% macro createObject ( input ) %}
        {% set output = { 'test' : 'Hello world' } %}
        {% set output = output|merge({'disabledLogo': 'true'}) %}
    {%  endmacro %}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just create a filter?

Comment: because the other conditions for this object to pass through other templates and are therefore very individual

Comment: Then u are doing something wrong. Adjust the data in the controller, not inside `twig`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that unfortunatelly.

If you need to modify some data in a certain way, your best bet would be to create a [Twig filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters).

Comment: because the other conditions for this object to pass through other templates and are therefore very individual